# Why the OS increase (+1) the processes session ID in OS Win7

Tags: windows-7

I have Win 7, every time the user log-off and log-on, for all processes on that physical server the Session ID is increasing +1, so after 10 log-on/off the processes which I'm using will saw - session ID 10, and it keeps increasing every log off/log on.

Why the OS not recycling the session ID #.

Thanks
Lior Grundshten

Comment: Why is this important?

Comment: I believe it's just a design decision

Answer (score 1):

It's computationally 'easier' to just keep incrementing the session numbers until the OS runs out, then start recycling. Windows is slow enough without doing silly things like trying to recycle session numbers before it's necessary.